# Can't access value from child component : Undefined - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I want to pass a value betwen components in order to switch from a list of candidates to another panel where i can edit the selected candidate.

Sadly, i get this error : ERROR TypeError: "this.listCandidateComponent is undefined" in my edit-candidate component when i try to log the candidate that i initialized in list-candidate component.

list-candidate.component.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody *ngFor="let candidate of candidates">
    <td><h4>{{ candidate.id }}</h4></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" style="margin: 1%"
         (click)="getCandidateById(candidate.id)" role="button">Modifier</a>
    </td>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

list-candidate.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-candidate',
  templateUrl: './list-candidate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-candidate.component.scss']
})
export class ListCandidateComponent implements OnInit {

  candidate: Candidate;
  candidates: Candidate[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCandidateList();
  }

  async getCandidateById(id: number) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.cookie.get('access_token')
    });
    const options = {
      headers
    };
    await this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, options)
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        (response: Candidate) => {
          console.log('GET request successful', response);
          this.candidate = response;
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('GET error : ', error);
        }
      );
    await this.router.navigate(['/candidates/edit']);
   }
```

edit-candidate.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-candidate',
  templateUrl: './edit-candidate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-candidate.component.scss']
})

export class EditCandidateComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  candidate: Candidate;

  @ViewChild(ListCandidateComponent) listCandidateComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.candidate = this.listCandidateComponent.candidate;
    console.log(this.candidate);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: it is right cause u don't really know if the http request is ended at the time you read the child component property, pls write down the edit-candidate.componet.html

Comment: Doesn't async/await  guarantee that the http request is ended before switching to the parent component ?

Comment: no, beacuse async function are async, is just the funtion to be "sync", so the this.getCandidateList(); call return a promise and resolve "later" on

Comment: edit-candidate.component.html is just a form that i would fill with the candidate i get in edit-candidate.component.ts. It's empty.

Comment: the "angular way" for this case is to use eventemitter and eventlistener to relate the 2 componets instead of  @ViewChild, "reacting" to

Comment: ok, i re-used @ViewChild because i did previously when creating a candidate with a child component address to create both candidate and his address in the same component (and it worked :o). Will try the eventemitter then. Thx ;)

Comment: if the components aren't directly related, you can use a service as a "storage" to save the selected candidate, and then retrive it from the edit component

Comment: Ok, i was trying to avoid too much code but if that's a better way..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are routing to an edit page..

```
await this.router.navigate(['/candidates/edit']);
```

You can't use ViewChild in this scenario.

You have to add params to your router.navigate like

```
await this.router.navigate(['/candidates/edit'], { queryParams: { candidateId: id } });
```

and in your edit component you have to read the queryParams

```
id: any;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.route.queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['candidateId'];
  });
```

}

Now just load your candidate with the id in your edit component and you'r finished :)

You placed Viewchild in your edit component. If you want to load List component with viewchild, anywhere in edit-candidate.component.html has to be something like

`<app-list-candidate>
</app-list-candidate>`

else it would always be undefined because list component is not child of edit component.

I hope it helps - sorry If I misunderstood your problem (: